# how selected control call function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

- i have a form with many controls(drop down list, check box, radio button ...).
- my form created dynamically and each form has different controls.
- some of controls must call function,
- my function must declare which control called it.

what can i do?
how name controls?
how manage which controls call or which of them not?
how my function know which control called it?

many thanks.

ps: i don't want to use server side controls, i use just client site controls.

Comment: the function to be called is same one?

Comment: thank you. yes. in fact some control must present himself to a function, and function alert which control selected, change or ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using `jQuery`, adding controls dynamically to a `<div class="controls">` .

Then you can do something like:

```
$(".controls").on("click", your_function);
```

In `your_function`:

```
function your_function(target){
    //target would be the control which fires `click` event
    //you can assign them different custom attributes
    //like <input mid="123" type="text" />
    //then get this custom attribute(mid)
    var identifier = $(target).attr("mid");
    //distinguish them by different identifier
}
```

Furthermore, if it involves `select` or `file` control, you should bind `change` event as well to make it more compatible.

Comment: thank you, it works. but in vs2010, when i put mid attribute i get this message: VALIDATION (XHTML 1.0 TRANSITIONAL):ATTRIBUTE 'MID' IS NOT A VALID ATTRIBUTE OF ELEMENT 'DIV'. is it correct to use this attribute? is it under seo or other standards? what do you think of using name instead of costume attribute

Comment: i found new attribute in html5 : data-*, what do you think of this? (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_standardattributes.asp)

Comment: @MohammadAdibi yeah sure, `data-*` is better choice for html5 compatible html